# Calculus for Economics

Tags: reference-request, economics

Please suggest me a good book for Calculus. I am a beginner. It would be better if you tell me which book would be appropriate for learning Calculus for understanding Economics.

Comment: If I were you, I would also consider using some online resources, such as Khan Academy, or one of the one line courses for intro calculus, such as on edx.org or coursera.org

Comment: Ok. I'll try edx.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The textbook I used for maths at undergraduate level was 'Essential Mathematics foe Economic Analysis' by Sydsaeter and Hammond. I don't know of any others for comparison but it was always helpful for me. I've got the 3rd edition but I imagine any edition will cover the calculus required.

Comment: Is this book having calculus for Economics?

Answer (score 1):

Any calculus book should be sufficient for basic economics.  For more advanced economics, you will have to learn some advanced calculus.  But if you are a true beginner, just start with something like Stewart or Thomas.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend the book "calculus" written by MIT Professor Gilbert Strang. It's useful for self-learners. You can also find his teaching videoes online.

Answer (score 1):

For a beginner that knows nothing about differentiation the absolute best is Geoff Renshaw's Maths for Economics. This textbook is especially good for self-study as Renshaw explains in simple language yet in a logical and step-by-step way all basic concepts.

Buy older and cheaper versions if available. It is not worth paying top dollar for the latest edition.